# Elastic search data aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

Having the following example type in index:

```
{
"_index": "aggs_20141028",
"_type": "aggobj",
"_id": "4aNpd7zlR5eTdA7o2I898A",
"_version": 1,
"_score": 1,
"_source": {
    "UserId": 4,
    "Created": "2014-10-28T09:40:22.0652362+02:00",
    "Path": "Path_0",
    "IntProp1": 1,
    "IntProp2": 87,
    "IntProp3": 903,
    "BoolProp1": false,
    "BoolProp2": true,
    "BoolProp3": false,
    "StringProp1": "StringProp_6",
    "StringProp2": "StringProp_6",
    "StringProp3": "StringProp_3"
    }
}
```

How to aggregate data in it for the following use cases?

1. Aggregate BoolProp (count) group by user, timeperiod (e.g. day, month), filter on startdate
2. Aggregate BoolProp (count) group timeperiod (e.g. day, month), filter on startdate, userId
3. Aggregate BoolProp (count) group by contentproperty, timeperiod (e.g. day, month), filter on startdate
4. Aggregate IntProp (sum) group by path, timeperiod, filter on startdate

Original ES documentation is quite hard to understand...
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-sum-aggregation.html

Answer (score 0):

you don't have a field startdate in your data - I'm assuming that you mean Created?
Also you have three BoolProp fields which are all boolean - it's not clear how you want to count them, e.g. are you counting whether they are present, true, etc.?

the size field will depend on the size of your data and will require tuning.

Here's how I'd approach the first requirement:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/aggs_20141028/aggobj/_search?pretty' -d '{
  "aggs": {
     "date_filter_agg": {
         "filter" : {
            "term": { "Created": "2014-10-28T09:40:22.0652362+02:00" }},
      "aggs" : {
       "user_agg" : {
         "terms": {"size": 0, "field" : "UserId"},
         "aggs" : {
             "date_agg": {  
                "date_histogram" : { "field" : "Created", "interval" : "month" },
                "aggs" : {
                    "BoolProp_count": {"sum" : {"script" : "(doc[\"BoolProp1\"].value == \"T\" ? 1 : 0) + (doc[\"BoolProp2\"].value == \"T\" ? 1 : 0) + (doc[\"BoolProp3\"].value == \"T\" ? 1 : 0)"} }  }}
}}}}}}}'
```

key things to note -

1. the date filter appears first and is run over all your search results.
2. results are then grouped by UserId then grouped by Created data in
3. monthly buckets Last field is the calculation of the value you want
4. returned value is last, i.e. the count of true BoolProp fields.

The answers to the other requirements should be very similar.